# How to catch unsuccessful httpclient calls when using forkJoin

Tags: angular6, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I'm trying to use Angular6 and combine a number of httpclient.get calls using forkjoin.

Currently forkjoin works well if all the http calls are successful. however i would like to catch and exception, return something, maybe the array item and continue on to the next http call.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Observer, forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'

public list = [
            {"id": 1, "img" : "image.png",  "color": "DodgerBlue", "network": {}, "config": {}, "name": "myname", "statsurl": "https://somewhere.com:8119", "poolurl": "https://somewhere.com"}}
    ];


let m = [...this.poollist];

let staturls = this.list.map(item => this.http.get(item.statsurl)
                                            .pipe(map((res:Response) => res)),
                                            .catchError(res => of({}))));


forkJoin(staturls).subscribe(data => {
  data.forEach(function(v, i) {
    m[i].config = v['config'];
  })
```

Thanks
Gary

Comment: you only need `.pipe(map((res:Response) => res))` if your server doesnt return json

Comment: Hi, Actually i wanted catchError to return an Object with a status code, so i defined it in (res => of({myobject}))));

Answer (score -1):

had an extra parenthesis

```
=> res)),
```

to

```
=> res),

let staturls = this.list.map(item => this.http.get(item.statsurl)
                                        .pipe(map((res:Response) => res),
                                        .catchError(res => of({})))));
```

Comment: `=> res),` should be `=> res)),`, there are 3 opening brackets, if the code is changed to what you put, there will only be 2 closing brackets, not 3